# Shift Register over long distances

Tags: shift-register

I am using a *SN74HC165 Shift Register* to read the signal from some switches. With the *SN74HC165* Integrated Circuit near to the microcontroller the circuit below works perfectly. But physically I have to put the microcontroller at a distance of 2.5m from the IC. With this distance I'm losing some data, mainly the K8 signal. I am using pull-up resistors with the value of 10K. Would anyone know a way to improve this signal and avoid data loss at this distance?

[image]

Comment: take an oscilloscope to the lines and check how the signal degraded.

Comment: What's your clockrate and how does the clock signal look?

Comment: Measuring what is going on is best. If you have no scope: try to lower the resistors to 4.7K or 2.2K. Start with R8 if K8 is most sensible.

Comment: You are "loosing data" from the K8 signal, but it's the STM32 that is distanced? Is that right? You mentioned 10K pullups, but those are not at the STM32...

Comment: Put 100 ohm resistors in the outputs of all signal drivers, for source-terminated waveform fidelity.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the clock signal in particular on an oscilloscope at the IC end, chances are it is ringing like a bell and causing the SR to clock multiple times.  You can try a series resistor of about 50-100 ohms in series with the clock drive (near the microcontroller), but that's not ideal.

It would be better to use an LVDS differential driver and receiver and a properly terminated twisted pair, at least for the clock signal.

Failing that, slowing the clock with an RC and using a Schmitt trigger (since the SN74HC165 lacks a ST clock input) such as 74HC14 to clean up the clock at the other end should work, provided it's acceptable to run the clock at a much lower frequency.

Comment: Your suggestion on the use of a Schmitt trigger (74HC14) is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious explanation seems to be propagation time (loosing of data from K8 switch seems to confirm that). Wires resistance can also be an explanation.

I would try to lower the baudrate between MCU and IC, making CLK signal being of a low enough frequency. Also, add delays between activation / deactivation of SH and CLK_INH signals and data transfer.

Doing that you will ensure that signals are propagated in a way that IC timings are respected.

Answer (score 1):

If by

> losing some data, mainly the K8 signal

you mean the K8 tends to be incorrect, the situation seems very odd, since each bit in the sequence is treated identically, regardless of the distance.

K8 is the first bit to go out, so your received sequence should be

[K8, K7, ..., K1]

If there is some timing problem (clock too early, too late), i.e. something to do with propagation delay, you would get something like

[?, K8, K7, ..., K2]

or

[K7, K6, ..., K1, ?]

where ? is some incorrectly sampled value.

I believe one of these is more likely than getting more errors is bit K8.

One potential problem, based on your diagram, is the missing ground connection of the microcontroller. Does it run tightly coupled to the data lines? Is not, you could have a huge inductance in your lines, which not only creates a low-pass filter (limiting your signal rise times and causing delay), but also creating large coupling between lines. For example, a rising edge in one signal (i.e. the clock), could couple to another (i.e. the data). Or vise versa. The shift register could even clock itself with a logic transition of its output pins.

Try running all cables close to each other.

What about the supply voltage connection between the two ICs? Are both IC's properly decoupled with a capacitor between VCC and ground? If not, you could see a large voltage drop when logic transitions happen. This could explain why you have a problem with the first bit and not the others. The load signal reads in all bits at a time, which could cause a large voltage drop temporarily, affecting the first bit going out, but stabilizes after that.

Try increasing the decoupling capacitance between VCC and GND at both ICs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your signals look like on a scope, but when I have issues due to long wires and non-differential signals, often a simple 0.1µF cap from the long-distance signal to ground helps to decouple noise. The optimal value of the cap can depend on the speeds/timing you need.